# Feynmf doesn't produce feynman diagram at all in TXC

Tags: packages, diagrams, texniccenter, metafont

I am trying to draw a feynman diagram using feynmf in TXC.
I use the following code

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{feynmf}
    \begin{document}
    \unitlength = 1mm
    % determine the unit for the size of diagram.
    ... here comes an example with feynmf
     \begin{fmffile}{one}   %one.mf will be created for this feynman diagram  
       \fmfframe(1,7)(1,7){     %Sets dimension of Diagram
       \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,62) %Sets size of Diagram
        \fmfleft{i1,i2} %Sets there to be 2 sources 
        \fmfright{o1,o2}    %Sets there to be 2  outputs
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1} %Labels one of the left sources
        \fmflabel{$e^+$}{i2} %Labels one of the left sources
        \fmflabel{${\ensuremath{\erlpm}}$}{o1} %Labels one of the right outputs
        \fmflabel{${\ensuremath{\erlpm}}$}{o2} %Labels one of the right outputs
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2} %Connects the sources with a vertex.
        \fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,o2} %Connects the outputs with a vertex.
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma/Z^0$}{v1,v2} %Labels the conneting line.
       \end{fmfgraph*}
      }
    \end{fmffile}
```

The thing is, that no error occurs, however no diagram is printed.
Searching the web I found that I have to run LaTeX, then run metafont and run LaTeX again.
Somehow I have to pre-produce the file "ome.mf" and run, I don't know how to do it, though.
Any ideas?

Comment: one.mf is produced by the first compilation with latex, so you need the sequence `latex -- mf -- latex`; apparently, texniccenter doesn't know that ... but i don't know how one might persuade it to do what's necessary.

Comment: @wasteofspace: you should turn your comment into an answer (perhaps explaining some more how to process the `.mf` on a terminal?).

Comment: I found a "script" that works on kile. I tried to use it on TeXNiC center but it doesn't work. No error occurs, no feynman appears though. What can I do?

Comment: @Thanos Did you try running Metafont from a DOS shell?

Comment: Also see [How to run Metafont in TeXnicCenter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49509/how-to-run-metafont-in-texniccenter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `(pdf)latex` on the file should produce a file called `one.mf` in the same directory as your main `.tex` file.

You need to open a command window (or DOS shell, or whatever it's called) `cd` to the directory and issue

```
mf one.mf
```

However, you can say

```
\usepackage{feynmp}
```

which will create `one.mp`. You'd run

```
mpost one.mp
```

This is vastly more efficient than the Metafont method.

For even more convenience, use the `feynmp-auto` package, which will automatically run `mpost` (for this to work with MikTex you have to add the `-enable-write18` switch to the argument list of `(pdf)latex`)

Comment: In TXC, you can add pre- and post-processor instructions to an output profile, including a "File path without extension" parameter, so adding the post-processor `mpost "%bm.mp"`, probably followed by another `(pdf)latex` run, should do the trick. If you add this to your default output profile make sure you add some error catching, since a non-existent `.mp` file will otherwise cause TXC to believe compilation failed and refuse to "compile & show" (it will compile, but due to the error won't show the result)