# How to run Metafont in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, metafont, feynmf

I want to create a Feynman diagram, with the `feynmf` package.
While compiling, no error occurs, but no diagram is produced.

I have searched through the net, and I found that I have to create an mf file.

The code I am using is

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{feynmf}
    \begin{document}
    \unitlength = 1mm
    % determine the unit for the size of diagram.
    ... here comes an example with feynmf
     \begin{fmffile}{one}   %one.mf will be created for this feynman diagram  
       \fmfframe(1,7)(1,7){     %Sets dimension of Diagram
       \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,62) %Sets size of Diagram
        \fmfleft{i1,i2} %Sets there to be 2 sources 
        \fmfright{o1,o2}    %Sets there to be 2  outputs
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1} %Labels one of the left sources
        \fmflabel{$e^+$}{i2} %Labels one of the left sources
        \fmflabel{${\ensuremath{\erlpm}}$}{o1} %Labels one of the right outputs
        \fmflabel{${\ensuremath{\erlpm}}$}{o2} %Labels one of the right outputs
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2} %Connects the sources with a vertex.
        \fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,o2} %Connects the outputs with a vertex.
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma/Z^0$}{v1,v2} %Labels the conneting line.
       \end{fmfgraph*}
      }
    \end{fmffile}
```

The thing is that I have to create one.mf file, run LaTeX, run one.mf and run LaTeX again.

How am I supposed to run and create run.mf?

Comment: The file `one.mf` is created when you compile the document with LaTeX; then you open a command shell in the same directory as the document and type `mf one` followed by the "return" key.

Comment: That's the point! How can I find TXC's command shell?

Comment: Not TeXnicCenter's: it's the standard DOS command shell.

Comment: A guy I was talking to uses WinEdit. He has his own command prompt. I thought it's the same with TXC. I don't know how to use the DOS shell... Any help could be of vital importance!

Comment: I tried to open one.mf with TXC in order to compile it.18 errors occur;I ignore them at first and run LaTeX again and guess what: No diagramm is printed...

Comment: I suggest you read up in the [feynmf manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) which states the order of operations in order to accomplish diagrams. Then read up on TeXnicCenter on how to create profiles, for instance here: [Metapost profile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5myn4H4uIw).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

egreg's suggestion of using MetaPost instead of MetaFont is the way to go. If you are not used to the command line, I'll suggest an easy way to convert your file in Windows.

Open `Notepad` and add the following line:

```
mpost %1
```

Then, when saving, use `Drop MF file here.cmd` as the name (don't forget to add the `.cmd` extension) and select `All files (*.*)` in the `Type` option. The follow figure illustrates this step: *(Sorry, my Windows is in Portuguese, but the idea is the same)*

[image: Notepad]

Now I have the following files in my folder:

[image: Files]

Compile `mydoc.tex` (where the `.tex` file is the one egreg suggested you to use) and the other files will be generated:

[image: Generation]

Now, time for the magic. Select `one.mp` and drag it over `drop MF file here.cmd` and release it:

[image: Drag and drop]

Wait some seconds and there we go!

[image: Final]

Now, compile `mydoc.tex` again and your diagram will be there:

[image: Screenshot]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Thank's a lot for your advice... But it didn't work...I get two errors.1.Cannot include graphics of type: mps, 2. Emergency Stop...

Comment: @Thanos: egreg updated his answer, could you try the new code? `:)`

Comment: Either eps or mps isn't working...

Comment: @Thanos: Which TeX distro do you use?

Comment: MikTex 2.8. My editor is TXC

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use `feynmp` in place of `feynmf`, nowadays. It's almost the same input, but it requires to run `mpost` instead of `mp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp} % <- change here
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{.1}{} % <- line to be added if using pdflatex
%\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{eps}{.1}{} % <- line to be added if using pdflatex
\begin{document}
\unitlength = 1mm
% determine the unit for the size of diagram.
... here comes an example with feynmf
 \begin{fmffile}{one}   %one.mf will be created for this feynman diagram  
   \fmfframe(1,7)(1,7){     %Sets dimension of Diagram
   \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,62) %Sets size of Diagram
    \fmfleft{i1,i2} %Sets there to be 2 sources 
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    %Sets there to be 2  outputs
    \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1} %Labels one of the left sources
    \fmflabel{$e^+$}{i2} %Labels one of the left sources
    \fmflabel{${\ensuremath{\erlpm}}$}{o1} %Labels one of the right outputs
    \fmflabel{${\ensuremath{\erlpm}}$}{o2} %Labels one of the right outputs
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2} %Connects the sources with a vertex.
    \fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,o2} %Connects the outputs with a vertex.
    \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma/Z^0$}{v1,v2} %Labels the conneting line.
   \end{fmfgraph*}
  }
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

When the picture changes one has to run from a shell `mpost one` and at the next run of LaTeX the correct picture will be included.

***In some minutes some suggestions about how to run Metapost will be added***

Comment: I have already tried feynmp but it didn't work either. The whole point is how to run mpost one, or one.mf or one.mp! I cannot find TXC's commant prompt or shell or window!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!!!

I added the following "script" after

```
    \DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{.1}{}
```

and before

```
    \begin{document}
```

The code is

```
    \makeatletter
    \def\endfmffile{%
      \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
      end.^^J%
      endinput;}%
      \if@fmfio
        \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
      \fi
      \ifnum\pdfshellescape=\@ne
        \immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}%
      \fi}
    \makeatother
```

The feynman shows up like charm!!! I also used another code insted of the first one posted my me

```
    \begin{fmffile}{oneone}
    \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    % Note that the size is given in normal parentheses
    % instead of curly brackets.
    % Define external vertices from bottom to top
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
    \end{fmfgraph}
    \end{fmffile}
```

Both codes produce nice diagrams. Thank you a lot guys for you effort and patience! For anyone who is to use this package: In order to make corrections to the diagrams, someone has to delete all files (.mp, .1, .t1, .txt) and do the proccess that Paulo described!