# Getting feynmp-auto to run in Mik-tex

Tags: feynmp-auto

I'm trying to run `feymp-auto` to run with MikTeX (in TeXniccentre). On an earlier post:

[Feynmf doesn't produce feynman diagram at all in TXC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48706/feynmf-doesnt-produce-feynman-diagram-at-all-in-txc)

egreg commented:

> "For this to work with MikTex you have to add the -enable-write18 switch to the argument list of (pdflatex)."

Does anyone know how exactly do you do this? Is it in the "build output profiles"?

[image: screenshot]

This is what I've done, doesn't seem to be making a difference though.

### Addendum

It works now, I didn't realise you had to run it twice!

Comment: Look for the configurations of TeXnicenter. You should find the commands executed when you compile some file. Then add the option `-enable-write18` to the `pdflatex` command.

Comment: This image show it for `latex` (`latex=>dvi`). Note the field *Command line arguments...*. You have to edit but for the option `latex=>pdf`. http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~eva/images/profiles.PNG

Comment: Here is the right image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aHfOr.png